# navbar-brand text flows out of navbar

Tags: html, css

While making a `navbar` for my page, the `navbar-brand` text simply flows out of the navbar if it gets too big. The interesting thing is that this doesn't happen with the the other list items of my `navbar`. It doesn't matter how much I increase the font size for the list items, the `navbar` simply grows with them. 
Here's the HTML-

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Brand Name</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="navbar_text" href="activities.php">Activities</a></li>
        <li><a class="navbar_text" href="result.php">Results</a></li>
        <li><a class="navbar_text" href="about_us.php">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS-

```
.navbar-nav {
float: right;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #282343;
}

.navbar_text {
    color: #9B9BD4;
    font-family: 'Arvo', Georgia, Times, serif;
    font-size: 39px;
    line-height: 70px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    color: #9B9BD4;
    font-family: 'Arvo', Georgia, Times, serif;
    font-size: 59px;
    line-height: 70px;
}
```

I want the brand text to be bigger than the list items. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried constraining the size of your brand by passsing it a max-height and max-width?

Comment: @DMrFrost I don't want to constrain the size of the brand. Rather I want it to be of a bigger size, but also to stay without the confines of the navbar.

Comment: stay without the confines of the navbar??  You mean stay within?  PLace it within your navbar and set its max-height to less then 100% and it will stay in its parent div.

Comment: @DMrFrost within*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by changing the line-height to 70px and padding to 0px of .navbar-brand.
Try this css .

```
.navbar-brand {
color: #9B9BD4;
font-family: 'Arvo', Georgia, Times, serif;
font-size: 59px;
line-height: 50px;
padding: 0px;
```

}

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want your contents to stay within your nav bar div, you can set their css styes

```
  max-height: 90%;
  max-width: 50px;
```

This will keep them neatly contrained inside of your nav div, while the nav itself can continue to resize.  Setting the max value will also allow your elements to continue to scale, but never leave your parent div.  max-height 90% will insure that your contents ae never bigger than 90% of the height of your nav bar.  (Adjust the values as you need)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you used the "float:right" selector.
When you use {float} - the element "goes out" of his borders in order to put himself at the place that was defined by you (right).